# Find out No of users who has not order since specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables: customer and order. I want to find out number of customers who have not ordered since 1 April 1996 using a query. Order table contains multiple records.

Customer Table Layout and some data:

[image]

Order Table Layout and some data:

[image]

Comment: Hello : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the number of customers who placed one or more orders but all orders were less than the specified date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    HAVING MAX(OrderDate) < '1996-04-01'
) AS x
```

If you want to include customers that placed 0 orders then use:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM customers
) - (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)
    FROM orders
    WHERE OrderDate >= '1996-04-01'
)
```

Comment: How can we cross check we have 5 Million records

Comment: Create appropriate indexes e.g. `orders.ix1(CustomerID, OrderDate)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDERS.CUST = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
AND ORDERS.ORDERDATE >= "1996-04-01");
```

Comment: Perhaps explaining how / why this works might be more useful..?

Comment: @JustCarty: I think that the expression is self-explaining. Select all the customers who *don't* have an entry in the orders table since 01 April 1996. Using exists/not exists is a very strong mechanism for questions like these.

Comment: I agree to a degree, however, I know that when I was learning, seeing two select statements together, and also the `SELECT 1` would have confused me somewhat. I, personally, think you shouldn't take someone's knowledge for granted when answering a question.

Comment: @JustCarty: The current 'other query' which uses a subquery is clearer? There are two selects (or even three) in those queries.

Comment: No, I think the other query is harder to read. Using subtraction in queries still confuses me for a second. Such as `ORDER BY -some_column ASC` to force the null values in that column to the bottom of the query. Perhaps it's just me, I just try and think back to when I was learning and how easily confused I got >_<

Comment: For 5 million rows I would run this query and get some coffee, or may be go to sleep.

Comment: @JustCarty, NOT EXISTS is quite expansive, for 5 millions rows it's going to be quite a long run. https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @SalmanA: Let the OP time each method - after adding suitable indexes - and then we'll see which method is faster.